# Extracting alphanumeric text from csv file

Tags: python, perl

I have a location grid (A-I and 1-9) that is referenced in a flat file (*.csv) in various forms that sometimes includes white-space, and random case, such as: 9-H, @ b 3, e-4, d4, c6, 5h, C2, i9, ... that is any combination of a through i and 1 through 9, including white space, ~ @ and -.

What would be a good way to handle extracting such alphanumeric characters? The output will ideally be in say another column preceding "Notes" or in another text file. I can read scripts and figure out what they do, but am not comfortable enough to write them yet.

Sample input file:

```
Record  Notes
46651   Adrian reported green-pylons are in central rack. (e-4)
46652   Jose enetered location of triangles in the uppur corner. (b/c6)
46207   [Location: 5h] Gabe located the long pipes in the near the far corner.
46205   Committee-reports are in boxes in holding area, @ b 3).
45164   Caller-nu,mbers @ 1A
45165   All carbon rod tackles 3 F and short (top rack)
45166   USB(3 Port) in C2
45167   Full tackle in b2.
45168    5b; USB(4 port)
45073   SHOVELs+ KIPER ON PET-FOOD (@g6), ALSO ATTEMPT-STALL AND DRAWCORD.
45169   Persistent CORDS ~i9
45170   Deliverate handball moved to D-2 on instructions from Pete
45440   slides and overheads + contact-sheets to 9-H (top bin).
45441   d7-slides and negatives (black and white)
<eof>
```

Desired output (in alpha-numeric format, either in same file, or new file)

```
Record  Location    Notes  
46651   E4  
46652   C6  
46205   A1  
...  
46169   I9
```

That is, always extract the latter set of characters.

Okay fellows, after getting "Use of uninitialized value $note in pattern match (m//) at" errors, I just went ahead with tried and am partly successful.

```
#   # starts with anything then space or punctuation then letter then number
if ($note =~ /.*[\s\~\p{Punct}]([a-iA-I])[\s\p{Punct}]*([0-9]).*/) {
    $note =~ s/.*[\s\~\p{Punct}]([a-iA-I])[\s\p{Punct}]*([0-9]).*/$1$2/x;

#   # starts line with letter then number
} elsif ($note =~ /^([a-iA-I])[\s\p{Punct}]*([0-9]).*/) {
   $note =~ s/^([a-iA-I])[\s\p{Punct}]*([0-9]).*/$1$2/x;

#   # after punctuation then number
} elsif ($note =~ /.*[\s\p{Punct}]([0-9])[\s\p{Punct}]*([a-iA-I]).*/) {
   $note =~ s/.*[\s\p{Punct}]([0-9])[\s\p{Punct}]*([a-iA-I]).*/$2$1/x;

#   # beginning of line with number
} elsif ($note =~ /^([0-9])[\s\p{Punct}]*([a-iA-I]).*/) {
    $note =~ s/^([0-9])[\s\p{Punct}]*([a-iA-I]).*/$2$1/x;

#   # empty line or no record of any grid location except "#7 asdfg" format
} elsif  ($note=~ "") {
    $note = "##";

}
```

The time the script is not very successful is when it encounters records such as 99994 and 99993.

99999   norecordofgridhere --
99998
99997   box #7 entered the array with out invoice.
99996   was down in h 7 and the coachela was in e 8 when I found off-field.
99994   cartons in office after 4 buckets
99993   6 boxes in office file cabinet top-shelf

The output now is:

99999   #       #       norecordofgridhere --
99998   #       #
99997   E       7       box #7 entered the array with out invoice.
99996   E       8       was down in h 7 and the coachela was in e 8 when I found off-field.
99994   B       4       cartons in office after 4 buckets
99993   B       6       6 boxes in office file cabinet top-shelf

There should be #s for 99994 and 99993. Where did I fail? How should I fix this?

I reckon, there is a much cleaner way, like using Text::CSV_XS, however, I ran into glitches with strawberry perl even after testing the modules were properly installed. So I am back into activestateperl.

Comment: Can you give the desired output for that example input?

Comment: Just to be clear: the things you want to grab are `e-4`, `b/c6`, `5h`, `b 3`, `1A`, `3 F`, `C2`, `b2`, `5b`, `g6`, `i9`, `D-2`, `9-H`, and `d7`?

Comment: Not only grab these, but list them as alpha-numeric, that is E4, C6, B3, A1, and so on for each record in the file.

Comment: In one place, you said the location for 46652 is `b/c6`. In other, you said it was `C6`. Which one is it?

Comment: @ikegami Sorry Fellow, I had wanted to describe it during edit, but on submit, the page just hung. I have now given it. All output will be the latter alpha-number, b/c6 will be C6. Thanks heaps for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
...

my $coord;
if ($note =~ /
   (?&DEL)

   ( (?&ROW) (?&SEP)?+ (?&COL)
   | (?&COL) (?&SEP)?+ (?&ROW)
   )

   (?&DEL)

   (?(DEFINE)
      (?<ROW> [a-hA-H]    )
      (?<COL> [1-9]       )
      (?<SEP> [\s~\@\-]++ )
      (?<DEL> ^ | \W | \z )
   )
/x) {
    $coord = $1;
    ( my $row = uc($coord) ) =~ s/[^A-H]//g;
    ( my $col = uc($coord) ) =~ s/[^1-9]//g;
    $coord = "$row$col";
}

...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Text::CSV_XS](https://metacpan.org/module/Text%3a%3aCSV_XS) to parse the CSV file, it's fast and accurate.

Then build a regular expression to match the IDs.

Finally, normalize each ID.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use v5.10;
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

use Text::CSV_XS;

# Build up the regular expression to look for IDs
my $Separator_Set  = qr{ [- ] }x;
my $ID_Letters_Set = qr{ [a-i] }xi;
my $ID_Numbers_Set = qr{ [1-9] }x;
my $Location_Re = qr{
    \b
    $ID_Letters_Set $Separator_Set? $ID_Numbers_Set |
    $ID_Numbers_Set $Separator_Set? $ID_Letters_Set
    \b
}x;

# Initialize Text::CSV_XS and tell it this is a tab separated CSV
my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new({
    sep_char => "\t",   # tab separated fields
}) or die "Cannot use CSV: ".Text::CSV_XS->error_diag ();

# Read in and discard the CSV header line.
my $headers = $csv->getline(*DATA);

# Output our own header line    
say "Record\tLocation\tNotes";

# Read each CSV row, extract and normalize the ID, and output a new row.
while( my $row = $csv->getline(*DATA) ) {
    my($record, $notes) = @$row;

    # Extract and normalize the ID
    my($id) = $notes =~ /($Location_Re)/;
    $id = normalize_id($id);

    # Output a new row
    printf "%d\t%s\t%s\n", $record, $id, $notes;
}


sub normalize_id {
    my $id = shift;

    # Return empty string if we were passed in a blank
    return '' if !defined $id or !length $id or $id !~ /\S/;

    my($letter) = $id =~ /($ID_Letters_Set)/;
    my($number) = $id =~ /($ID_Numbers_Set)/;

    return uc($letter).$number;
}

__END__
Record  Notes
46651   Adrian reported green-pylons are in central rack. (e-4)
46652   Jose enetered location of triangles in the uppur corner. (b/c6)
46207   [Location: 5h] Gabe located the long pipes in the near the far corner.
46205   Committee-reports are in boxes in holding area, @ b 3).
45164   Caller-nu,mbers @ 1A
45165   All carbon rod tackles 3 F and short (top rack)
45166   USB(3 Port) in C2
45167   Full tackle in b2.
45168    5b; USB(4 port)
45073   SHOVELs+ KIPER ON PET-FOOD (@g6), ALSO ATTEMPT-STALL AND DRAWCORD.
45169   Persistent CORDS ~i9
45170   Deliverate handball moved to D-2 on instructions from Pete
45440   slides and overheads + contact-sheets to 9-H (top bin).
45441   d7-slides and negatives (black and white)
```